# Object size in c++ is unpredictable

Tags: c++, object, memory, size, sizeof

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Test
{
    int a;
    double d;
    char c;
};

int main()
{
    cout<<sizeof(int)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(double)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(char)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(Test)<<endl;
    Test sobj;
    Test *dobj = new Test();
    cout<<dobj<<endl;
    dobj++;
    cout<<dobj<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(sobj)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(dobj)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4
8
1
24
00380A08
00380A20
24
4
```

Here My question is when we print size of class using sizeof operator, it shows as 24 bytes as there is no padding applied it is clear, but when I see difference between addresses it is showing class size as 12 bytes, how is memory being allocated..??

Comment: Where are you seeing 12 bytes?

Comment: 0x00380A20 - 0x00380A08 = 0x18 = 24 (base 10). The addresses in your example are printed in base 16 (hexadecimal).

Comment: Why do you think no padding is being applied?

Comment: There is definitely padding applied: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb6a1b3721b875f0 your example corresponds to Layout1, where there is padding after the int (to align the double on an 8-byte boundary) and padding after the char (to make the whole struct align on an 8-byte boundary), giving a total of 24 bytes for the struct. The other two layouts can pack the int and char fields into the same 8-byte area, so the structs have size 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The addresses are in hexadecimal (as you can see from the `A`). 0x20 is 32 in decimal: The difference (in decimal) is not 20 - 8, it's 32 - 8 = 24.

Comment: How about 0x20=32, and 32-8 = 24

Comment: @Calvin Yes, thank you. It appears I can't do math involving two digit numbers.

Answer (score 2):

First, your confusion comes from the addresses being printed in hexadecimal (base 16). The differing parts of the two addresses are 0x20 (which is 32 in decimal) and 0x08 (which is 8 in decimal). The difference between these two numbers is 0x18 (hexadecimal), or 24 in decimal.

Secondly, there is most certainly some padding applied. Based on the numbers for the size of various types, in your question, consider the following code that defines the fields of your struct in three different orders:

(Live example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb6a1b3721b875f0)

```
#include <iostream>

struct Layout1 {
    int a;
    double b;
    char c;
};

struct Layout2 {
    int a;
    char b;
    double c;
};

struct Layout3 {
    double a;
    int b;
    char c;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(Layout1) << "\n";
    std::cout << sizeof(Layout2) << "\n";
    std::cout << sizeof(Layout3) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Remember that in this example, a double is 8 bytes, an int is 4 bytes, and a char is 1 byte. The layout of each struct will be as follows, where `i` represents one byte of the int, `c` the char, and `d` one byte of the double. The symbol `-` represents one byte of padding.

```
                    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3
i i i i - - - - d d d d d d d d c - - - - - - -  // layout 1
i i i i c - - - d d d d d d d d                  // layout 2
d d d d d d d d i i i i c - - -                  // layout 3
```

In the first layout, the double member must be aligned on an 8-byte boundary, so you get four bytes of padding after the int member. The whole struct must also have the same alignment as the most strict alignment of its members, i.e. that of the double. For this reason, there are seven bytes of padding after the char member.

In the second layout, the double must still be on an 8-byte boundary, but the char need not; it can be packed immediately after the int, leaving only three bytes of padding before the double. Since the struct ends with the double, no end-padding is required.

In the third layout, the double starts the struct, and the int (which has 4-byte alignment) can follow it immediately (since 8 is a multiple of 4). The char (one-byte alignment) can follow the int, but again the whole struct needs to align on 8-byte boundaries, so there are 3 bytes of padding after the char field.

The program above will therefore output:

```
24
16
16
```

Comment: Hi Everyone thanks a lot for clear explanation. I am aware of padding but mistakenly i wrote " there is no padding applied" instead of " there is padding applied". And regarding the difference in address is cleared. :-)

Comment: If you made a mistake you should edit your question to correct it.